# How do I carry out Conditional Navigation with Android Jetpack?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-viewmodel

I am trying to enable users to get to my homepage once they have logged in, but I am trying to do this using Android Conditional Navigation. The problem is I am using android Firebase to authenticate my users before they proceed to this screen and need to create a viewmodel for it but i do not know how to refactor the online guide to achieve this result can anyone point me to what I need to do?

Thank you

Here is the guide for the ViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public enum AuthenticationState {
        UNAUTHENTICATED,        // Initial state, the user needs to authenticate
        AUTHENTICATED,          // The user has authenticated successfully
        INVALID_AUTHENTICATION  // Authentication failed
    }

    final MutableLiveData<AuthenticationState> authenticationState =
            new MutableLiveData<>();
    String username;

    public LoginViewModel() {
        // In this example, the user is always unauthenticated when MainActivity is launched
        authenticationState.setValue(AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED);
        username = "";
    }

    public void authenticate(String username, String password) {
        if (passwordIsValidForUsername(username, password)) {
            this.username = username;
            authenticationState.setValue(AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED);
        } else {
            authenticationState.setValue(AuthenticationState.INVALID_AUTHENTICATION);
        }
    }

    public void refuseAuthentication() {
       authenticationState.setValue(AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED);
    }

    private boolean passwordIsValidForUsername(String username, String password) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Topic reference can be found at : https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this tutorial from @AlexMamo for more details:

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336

I have completely modified the `LoginViewModel`.

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = "debinf LogVIEWMODEL";

    private LoginRepository loginRepository;

    // https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional
    // https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-login/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/firebaseui_login_sample/LoginViewModel.kt

    public LoginViewModel() {
        loginRepository = new LoginRepository();

    }

    public LiveData<FirebaseUser> getFirebaseUserFromAuthState() {
        return loginRepository.getFirebaseUserFromAuthState();
    }

    public LiveData<AuthResult> getFirebaseAuthResultFromPhoneSignIn(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        return loginRepository.getFirebaseAuthResultFromPhoneSignIn(phoneAuthCredential);
    }

    public LiveData<AuthResult> getFirebaseAuthResultFromEmailSignIn(String email, String password) {
        return loginRepository.getFirebaseAuthResultFromEmailSignIn(email, password);
    }

}
```

Below is `LoginRepository`.

```
public class LoginRepository {

    public LiveData<FirebaseUser> getFirebaseUserFromAuthState() {
        return new FirebaseAuthLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<AuthResult> getFirebaseAuthResultFromPhoneSignIn(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        return new FirebaseSignInLiveData(phoneAuthCredential);
    }

    public LiveData<AuthResult> getFirebaseAuthResultFromEmailSignIn(String email, String password) {
        return new FirebaseSignInLiveData(email, password);
    }
}
```

The Class `FirebaseAuthLiveData` was used to check if user is logged in.

```
public class FirebaseAuthLiveData extends LiveData<FirebaseUser> {

    // https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-login/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/firebaseui_login_sample/FirebaseUserLiveData.kt

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            setValue(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser());
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }
}
```

`FirebaseSignInLiveData` is used for sign in either using phone number or email and password.

```
public class FirebaseSignInLiveData extends LiveData<AuthResult> {

    public static final String TAG = "debinf SignInLiveData";

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    private PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential;
    private String email, password;

    private boolean isPhoneAuthentication;

    private AuthResult authResult;

    public FirebaseSignInLiveData(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        isPhoneAuthentication = true;
        this.phoneAuthCredential = phoneAuthCredential;
    }

    public FirebaseSignInLiveData(String email, String password) {
        isPhoneAuthentication = false;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> onCompleteListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                authResult = task.getResult();
                setValue(authResult);

            } else {

                setValue(authResult);
                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // The verification code entered was invalid
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        if (isPhoneAuthentication) {
            firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener);
        } else {
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener);
        }

    }

}
```

I've placed my conditional navigation in `MainActivity`, because I do not want user to navigate to anywhere before making login. But I think it's OK if you place the condition in other fragment such as Profile.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // REDIRECT TO LOGIN IF NOT LOGGED IN - CONDITIONAL NAVIGATION
    LoginViewModel loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    loginViewModel.getFirebaseUserFromAuthState().observe(this, new Observer<FirebaseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: SAVE USER DATA AND GO TO MAIN FRAGMENT");

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN - REDIRECTING TO LOGIN");
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_start_loginFragment);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

By adding `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to our **global action** in `mainnav_graph.xml`, the app will close if user do not complete login.

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainnav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.SectorMain.MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

    <!-- Global action-->
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_start_loginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/login_navgraph"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/mainnav_graph"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/login_navgraph"
        app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
            android:name="com.myapp.LoginFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_termsFragment"
                app:destination="@id/termsFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/termsFragment"
            android:name="com.myapp.TermsFragment"
            android:label="fragment_terms"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_terms" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_termsFragment_to_userregisterFragment"
                app:destination="@id/userregisterFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/userregisterFragment"
            android:name="com.myapp.UserregisterFragment"
            android:label="fragment_userregister"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_userregister" />
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

After getting `phoneAuthCredential`, the user can sign in such as below in `LoginFragment`

```
private void sighInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

    Log.i(TAG, "sighInWithPhoneAuthCredential: ");
    loginViewModel.getFirebaseAuthResultFromPhoneSignIn(phoneAuthCredential).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(AuthResult authResult) {
            if (authResult != null) {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authResult.getUser();
                if (firebaseUser != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Add listener to User's node in real time database or firestore");
                    /*navController.popBackStack(R.id.mainnav_graph, false);
                            navController.navigate(R.id.mainnav_graph);*/

                    // pop up LoginFragment and go to MainFragment
                    NavOptions.Builder navBuilder = new NavOptions.Builder();
                    NavOptions navOptions = navBuilder
                            .setPopUpTo(R.id.mainnav_graph, true)
                            .build();
                    NavHostFragment.findNavController(LoginFragment.this).navigate(R.id.mainFragment, null, navOptions);
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "User not found");
                    mVerificationId = null;
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "The verification code entered was invalid");
                mVerificationId = null;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The last step is to remove the toolbar's back button. For that, we need to define our **top level destinations** in `MainActivity`, that is `R.id.mainFragment` and `R.id.loginFragment`.

```
appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.mainFragment, R.id.loginFragment)
                        .build();
```

I hope it helps!